# totcount gives wrong chapter count when appendices present

Tags: counters, totcount

I found that `totcount` gives the wrong chapter count when appendices are present. In the following MWE, the chapter count should be 3 but is actually 1:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{chapter}
\begin{document}
There are \total{chapter} chapters.
\chapter{A}
\chapter{B}
\appendix
\chapter{C}
\end{document}
```

When `\appendix` is commented out, the count is correct. Am I misusing the package, making a mistake, or this is a bug?

Comment: Of course, since `appendix` resets the chapter counter

Comment: Then how can I get around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit note**: The `assoccnt` package has a successor named `xassoccnt` which is extended compared to `assoccnt`. It incorporates some features that `totcount` provides too.

The package `assoccnt` can be used to step an associated counter each time another ('master') counter is stepped, regardless if the master counter is reset in between. In conjunction with `totcount` the task is easily solved, but don't reset (or change) the associated counter manually of course.

The reason why `totcount` itself can't do this is not `totcount`s fault. The `\appendix` command resets the chapter counter and after one `\chapter` in the appendix, the chapter counter value is `1`, this value is written to the `.aux` file in the end, making `totcount` believe, there's only one chapter in the file finally.

`assoccnt` 'hacks' into `\addtocounter{...}{}` (the basic command behind `\stepcounter` or `\refstepcounter` and increases the driven counter simultaneously. This even works if the master counters are reset with `chngcntr` etc. or `\@addtoreset` features.

Basically any counter can be used as master counters and there might be more than one of them. In the end, each master counter can have many driven (associated) counters themself.  (However, the page counter is little bit tricky!)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{assoccnt}

\newtotcounter{totalchapters}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{chapter}{totalchapters} % Associate the driven counter `totalchapters` to the master counter `chapter`
\begin{document}
There are \total{totalchapters} chapters.
\chapter{A}
\chapter{B}
\appendix
\chapter{C}
\chapter{D}
\chapter{E}
\chapter{F}
\chapter{G}
\chapter{H}
\chapter{I}
\end{document}
```

[image]