# calc breaks assoccnt?

Tags: calculations, totcount, assoccnt

I want to use `totcount` to get the number of parts and chapters in my document. To get the correct number of chapters in the presence of appendices, I use `assoccnt` (see [totcount gives wrong chapter count when appendices present](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269337/totcount-gives-wrong-chapter-count-when-appendices-present)). At the same time, I need to use `calc` for reasons that are not important for this question. When both `assoccnt` and `calc` are used, the chapter count is incorrect. With `calc` commented out, the chapter count is correct. The order of the usepackage commands is immaterial. How can I keep using `calc` but get `assoccnt` to work properly?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{assoccnt}
\regtotcounter{part}
\newtotcounter{chaptertot}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{chapter}{chaptertot}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
There are \total{part} parts and \total{chaptertot} chapters.
\part{I}
\chapter{A}
\chapter{B}
\part{II}
\chapter{E}
\chapter{F}
\appendix
\chapter{C}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Correct, I was not precise enough and will amend my question.

Comment: @HarishKumar: Here I am... and unfortunately : There's some error, yes. I've to investigate this bug

Comment: Yes, the package `calc` does some 'weird' things I had not in mind when I wrote `assoccnt` about one year ago. I've to do some redesign, perhaps I can get this done today. I had a rewrite in mind using `expl3` for the future.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug in a package that has been fixed.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Yes, that's a good idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit (2017/04/16)**

The newer version `xassoccnt` (starting from v1.2) has a combined feature of total counters and association to a driver counter), see the shorter version of the originally posted solution at the end,please.

Yes, there was a stupid bug in my package `assoccnt` -- it's related to the fact that counters from the driver counter reset list are stepped too, which is complete non-sense -- it was my fault.

I've made a bug-fix -- it's available from my github directory:

**Edit** There was another bug introduced when the first bug was done ;-)

I've uploaded `assoccnt` version 0.7 to CTAN. Place `assoccnt.sty` from that package in the local directory of your source. (I've just uploaded it to CTAN as well)

This should compile now correctly, with the correct values:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{assoccnt}

\regtotcounter{part}
\newtotcounter{chaptertot}
\newtotcounter{tabletot}

\DeclareAssociatedCounters{chapter}{chaptertot}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{table}{tabletot}



\begin{document}

There are \total{part} parts and \total{chaptertot} chapters and \total{tabletot} tables.
\part{I}
\chapter{A}

\begin{table}
  \caption{First table}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Second table}
\end{table}


\chapter{B}
\part{II}
\chapter{E}
\chapter{F}
\appendix
\chapter{C}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}

\regtotcounter{part}

\DeclareTotalAssociatedCounters{chapter}{chaptertot}
\DeclareTotalAssociatedCounters{table}{tabletot}



\begin{document}

There are \total{part} parts and \TotalValue{chaptertot} chapters and \TotalValue{tabletot} tables.
\part{I}
\chapter{A}

\begin{table}
  \caption{First table}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Second table}
\end{table}


\chapter{B}
\part{II}
\chapter{E}
\chapter{F}
\appendix
\chapter{C}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So you were busy for the day :)

Comment: @HarishKumar: No, not all. The bug was quite easy to find ;-)

Comment: Not sure how to best handle this because my question was put on hold, but for the benefit of anybody else who might stumble across this problem, I just wanted to note that I contacted Christian directly via email because I could not reproduce the behavior with the new assoccnt.sty. He's since updated it once more, which has fixed the problem I reported.