# calc and xassoccnt incompatible?

Tags: calc, xassoccnt

I'm getting LaTeX warning:

```
 Package xassoccnt Warning: Warning: Package "calc" is loaded -- this is not
 (xassoccnt)                recommended for xassoccnt
```

with

```
 calc 2017/05/25 v4.3
 xassoccnt 2018/06/10 - v1.6a
```

Answers at [calc breaks assoccnt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269731/calc-breaks-assoccnt/269794#269794) suggest the issue was resolved. But apparently not.

What should one do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a screenshot from page 9 of the user guide of the `xassoccnt` package (version 1.6a, 2018/06/10); this seems to be the version you're using.

[image]

In short, as long as you load `calc` *before* `xassoccnt`, you'll get away with a warning message.

Comment: Well copied from document, well written ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - It's good to have you back! Providing an excerpt of what you wrote is the best I could come up with...

Comment: Thank you very much. I am not really back, I am just on a short hiatus from my TeX hiatus... just because I need to practice TeX a little bit in order to pursue my own projects... and I am on Xmas vacation, so plenty of time