# Display maximum value of counter per section

Tags: counters, totcount

I'd like to display/get the maximum value of a counter that it reaches per section.

I have found a way to get the total/maximum value of a counter in the entire document so far, but I fail to get it working per section.

Is this even possible, perhaps with another package or would I need a custom command?

## Picture of problem

[image: screenshot of problem]

## MWE

```
\documentclass[
paper=a4,
DIV=15,
parskip=half
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{
lmodern,
totcount,
comment,
}

%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\newcounter{counterPERsection}[section]
\regtotcounter{counterPERsection}
\newcounter{anothercounter}
\regtotcounter{anothercounter}

\begin{comment}
\newcommand{\callingcounters}{%
    \stepcounter{counterPERsection}\arabic{counterPERsection}\\
    \stepcounter{anothercounter}\arabic{anothercounter}.\total{anothercounter}
}
\end{comment}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% NOT        %%%%%%%
%%%    WORKING %%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\begin{comment}
\newcommand{\callingcounters}{%
    \stepcounter{counterPERsection}\arabic{counterPERsection}.\total{counterPERsection}\\
    \stepcounter{anothercounter}\arabic{anothercounter}.\total{anothercounter}
}
%\end{comment}



\begin{document}
    
\section{First section}

\callingcounters

\callingcounters

\callingcounters

\callingcounters

\section{Second section}

\callingcounters

\callingcounters

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `xcntperchap` package that was written with this purpose.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcntperchap}

\newcounter{dummy} % for “total” counters

\newcounter{counterPERsection}[section]
\RegisterTrackCounter{section}{counterPERsection}

\newcounter{anothercounter}
\RegisterTrackCounter{dummy}{anothercounter}

% initialize the total counters
\stepcounter{dummy}

\newcommand{\callingcounters}{%
  \stepcounter{counterPERsection}%
  \arabic{counterPERsection}.%
  \ObtainTrackedValueExp{section}{counterPERsection}%
  \\*
  \stepcounter{anothercounter}\arabic{anothercounter}.%
  \ObtainTrackedValueExp{dummy}{anothercounter}%
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % just for this example

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\callingcounters

\callingcounters

\callingcounters

\callingcounters

\section{Second section}

\callingcounters

\callingcounters

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, thank you. :) But I have a problem. While your MWE works/compiles fine on my machine, the final version in my document does not. First it threw an error because of `calc` being loaded, but with Mico's trick from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461893/calc-and-xassoccnt-incompatible) that went away. Finally, the value for both instances of `\ObtainTrackedValueExp{..` are a 0/zero. Would you happen to have any clue as to what I could do to zero in on the cause for that?

Comment: I discovered a `.cpc`-file in the folder, which has this content: https://pastebin.com/FwbFLb2w (your "dummy" being "totcounter" here) If I set the zeros to different values and save the file, the document displays these values after the next latex run. Then with the next run, they go back to 0.

Comment: @henry Sorry, I can't debug what I can't see. I added `\usepackage{calc}` *before* `xcntperchap` and have no problem. It's useless to edit the `.cpc` file, because it gets rewritten at each run.

Comment: This is so frustrating. I have been to hell and back for this. Can I send you a version of my document?

Comment: @henry You should rather ask a new question with an example that fails, with details on the TeX distribution you're running.

Comment: I know. On it. :)

Comment: I found the issue lying with amsmath, amssymb and siunitx. If I comment out amsmath and amssymb (both with zero options) and later on situnitx (loaded with a few options), it works. However I am unable to reproduce it so I am actually quite fed up with this and done for today. :( If I somehow happen to to make it work, I will post again about this.

Comment: @henry I added `amsmath`, `amssymb` and `siunitx`. No issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a version of `\label` and `\ref`, but you have to manually save the counter values where you want them saved.  `\AtEndDocument` won't cut it.

You can use \currentlabel to save almost anything.

```
\documentclass[
paper=a4,
DIV=15,
parskip=half
]{scrartcl}

%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% easier to remove than use
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{lmodern, totcount, comment,}

%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\newcounter{counterPERsection}[section]
\newcounter{anothercounter}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\currentlabel}[2]{% #1 = text, #2 = label name
  \edef\@currentlabel{#1}%
  \label{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\callingcounters}[2]{% #1 = total counterPERsection, #2 = total anothercounter
    \stepcounter{counterPERsection}\arabic{counterPERsection}.#1\\
    \stepcounter{anothercounter}\arabic{anothercounter}.#2
}
%\end{comment}



\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\callingcounters{\ref{CPS1}}{\ref{AC}}

\callingcounters{\ref{CPS1}}{\ref{AC}}

\callingcounters{\ref{CPS1}}{\ref{AC}}

\callingcounters{\ref{CPS1}}{\ref{AC}}

\currentlabel{\thecounterPERsection}{CPS1}
\section{Second section}

\callingcounters{\ref{CPS2}}{\ref{AC}}

\callingcounters{\ref{CPS2}}{\ref{AC}}

\currentlabel{\thecounterPERsection}{CPS2}
\currentlabel{\theanothercounter}{AC}
\end{document}
```