# Counting chapters and appendices

Tags: memoir, counters, totcount, assoccnt, xassoccnt

During my [last experiences with cross-referencing on total counts between different files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/337263/44348), a problem of counting of chapters and appendices appears.

As a MWE we can use a MWE given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269338/44348)  with some modifications.

It happens that a simple command like  `\setcounter{truechapters}{\value{totalchapters}-\value{chapter}}` does not work.

I guess, that the reason is in a wrong using of these values.

The question is how to get three counts (total chapters, appendices and true chapters) in one pdf in a simple and reasonable way?

Note, please, also  that I cannot use `\zlabel` like it is described by Heiko [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/337344/44348)

Here is my MWE:

`MyBook.tex`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{assoccnt}

\newtotcounter{totalchapters}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{chapter}{totalchapters} % Associate the driven counter `totalchapters` to the master counter `chapter`

\AtBeginDocument{
    %% register a counter on the basis of the last chapter in totcounter
    \regtotcounter{chapter}
}

\newcounter{truechapters}


\begin{document}

\chapter{A}
\chapter{B}
\appendix
\chapter{C}
\chapter{D}
\chapter{E}
\chapter{F}
\chapter{G}
\chapter{H}
\chapter{I}


There are \total{totalchapters} total chapters.


There are \total{chapter} appendix chapters.


%here we need to count the difference of two previous counters
%\setcounter{truechapters}{\value{totalchapters}-\value{chapter}} 


There are \thetruechapters \: true chapters.



\end{document}
```

A screenshot of MyBook.pdf is below:

[image]

Comment: Please change for future purposes to `xassoccnt`. I won't update `assoccnt`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use both the LaTeX2e-kernel-macro `\addtocounter` and the
eTeX-primitive `\numexpr` for calculations.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{assoccnt}

\newtotcounter{totalchapters}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{chapter}{totalchapters} % Associate the driven counter `totalchapters` to the master counter `chapter`

\AtBeginDocument{
    %% register a counter on the basis of the last chapter in totcounter
    \regtotcounter{chapter}
}
\newcounter{truechapters}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A}
\chapter{B}
\appendix
\chapter{C}
\chapter{D}
\chapter{E}
\chapter{F}
\chapter{G}
\chapter{H}
\chapter{I}

There are \total{totalchapters} total chapters.

There are \total{chapter} appendix chapters.

%here we need to count the difference of two previous counters
\setcounter{truechapters}{\value{totalchapters}}%
\addtocounter{truechapters}{-\value{chapter}}%

There are \thetruechapters \: true chapters.

\setcounter{truechapters}{\numexpr\value{totalchapters}-\value{chapter}\relax}%

There are \thetruechapters \: true chapters.

\end{document}
```

Comment: @ Ulrich Diez, thank you for the explanations! I have just updated the question and deleted all bugs in counter's abbreviations.

Comment: @UlrichDiez, the edit you are talking about was mainly edited by Vladimir and I am not sure, what I have done except approving the edit. Sorry, if the edit of Vladimir that I approved was not in your sense.

Answer (score 6):

Define three new counters, for the main chapters, for the appendix and for the total.

The trick here is to add code to `\appendix` for saving the number of chapters so far in `truechapters` and resetting the counter for the number of appendices.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{totcount,assoccnt}

\newcounter{truechapters}
\regtotcounter{truechapters}

\newcounter{totalchapters}
\newcounter{appendixchapters}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{chapter}{totalchapters,appendixchapters}
\regtotcounter{totalchapters}
\regtotcounter{appendixchapters}

\preto\appendix{%
  % save the number of true chapters
  \setcounter{truechapters}{\value{chapter}}%
  % reset the number of chapters
  \setcounter{appendixchapters}{0}%
}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter

There are \total{totalchapters} total chapters.

There are \total{appendixchapters} appendix chapters.

There are \total{truechapters} true chapters.

\mainmatter

\chapter{A}
\chapter{B}
\appendix
\chapter{C}
\chapter{D}
\chapter{E}
\chapter{F}
\chapter{G}
\chapter{H}
\chapter{I}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ egreg, thank you so much! This way of problem solving is very interesting too! It uses more user-friendly names of counters. I mean especially `appendixchapters` instead of `chapters`.

Comment: This solution was the only one which didn't cause an error for a figure numbered/labeled "0.1", for me at least

Answer (score 6):

A variant of egreg's solution, this time using the up-to-date `xassoccnt` package (being the successor of `assoccnt`), which has a partial support for total counters.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}% Version 1.2 or higher, current version is 1.7

\NewTotalDocumentCounter{appendixchapters}
\DeclareTotalAssociatedCounters{chapter}{truechapters,totalchapters}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \SuspendCounters{truechapters}
  \AddAssociatedCounters{chapter}{appendixchapters}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

There are \TotalValue{totalchapters} total chapters.

There are \TotalValue{appendixchapters} appendix chapters.

There are \TotalValue{truechapters} true chapters.

\mainmatter

\chapter{A}
\chapter{B}
\appendix
\chapter{C}
\chapter{D}
\chapter{E}
\chapter{F}
\chapter{G}
\chapter{H}
\chapter{I}

\end{document}
```

[image]